# Array.length returns fixed value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have  DIV's which I pass data into based on different selections on my page. I append these values in an array to create a MYSQL query. When the page loads a few MySQL clauses are set  `SELECT FROM JOIN ON LIMIT 1000` and more values can be appended in between these pre-loaded clauses to achieve something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM abop_stats 
JOIN call_outcome ON abop_stats.outcome_idfk = call_outcome.id     
ORDER BY outcome_idfk ASC 
LIMIT 1000
```

Before the page was loading with  2 sets of `JOIN` & `ON` clauses so I tried to write an if statement to check the length of the query and if it exceeded a certain amount add the second set of clauses.

This didn't work so I tried to `console.log` my array length and it prints a fixed value of `16` on load and the same value whenever options are added into the `DIV's` so the displayed Query (html) isn't the same as the one on the `console` (because the second set of MySQL clauses aren't being being added).

My Code:

```
function query() {
    var qry = [];
    qry.push($('#select').html());
    qry.push($('#selection').html());
    qry.push($('#from').html());
    qry.push($('#table').html());
    qry.push($('#join').html());
    qry.push($('#table2').html());
    qry.push($('#on').html());
    qry.push($('#tablejoin').html());
    if (qry.length > 10) {
        qry.push($('#join2').html());
        qry.push($('#table3').html());
        qry.push($('#on2').html());
        qry.push($('#tablejoin2').html());
    }
    qry.push($('#precondition').html());
    qry.push($('#column').html());
    qry.push($('#condition').html());
    qry.push($('#input').html());
    qry.push($('#precondition2').html());
    qry.push($('#column2').html());
    qry.push($('#condition2').html());
    qry.push($('#limiter').html());
    var fullqry = qry.join(" ");
    var length = qry.length;
    console.log(qry.length);
    console.log(fullqry);
    return fullqry;
}
```

Why is my `array.length` giving a static value?

Comment: What do you mean by a static value?

Comment: The place you are performing the check `qry.length > 10` always fails, because at that time, the array will have only length of 8. So, those won't be added into array resulting in array length to 16 always.

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu If I place the If statement at the top ait still loads with 16, how would I fix this??

Comment: Why you are checking `qry.length` to 10 ?

Comment: @user3062358 Why do you need it? Place it at the end.

Comment: On a side note, is this query ever going to actually go anywhere near a proper, live database?  Don't trust data from the client in this way.  This isn't even [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), it's just allowing a web client to use their developer tools to run whatever query they want on your database.

Comment: @Doodlebunch positioning is important as per SQL syntax, I managed to fix it by checking for different condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do some simple math by following the code execution.

```
function query() {
    var qry = [];// qry.length = 0;
    qry.push($('#select').html()); // qry.length = 1;
    qry.push($('#selection').html());// qry.length = 2;
    qry.push($('#from').html());// qry.length = 3;
    qry.push($('#table').html());// qry.length = 4;
    qry.push($('#join').html());// qry.length = 5;
    qry.push($('#table2').html());// qry.length = 6;
    qry.push($('#on').html());// qry.length = 7;
    qry.push($('#tablejoin').html());// qry.length = 8;
    if (qry.length > 10) {// qry.length = 8; 8 > 10 = false; do not parse 
        qry.push($('#join2').html());
        qry.push($('#table3').html());
        qry.push($('#on2').html());
        qry.push($('#tablejoin2').html());
    }
    qry.push($('#precondition').html());// qry.length = 9;
    qry.push($('#column').html());// qry.length = 10;
    qry.push($('#condition').html());// qry.length = 11;
    qry.push($('#input').html());// qry.length = 12;
    qry.push($('#precondition2').html());// qry.length = 13;
    qry.push($('#column2').html());// qry.length = 14;
    qry.push($('#condition2').html());// qry.length = 15;
    qry.push($('#limiter').html());// qry.length = 16;
    var fullqry = qry.join(" ");
    var length = qry.length;// qry.length = 16; set length to 16
    console.log(qry.length);// qry.length = 16; print 16
    console.log(fullqry);
    return fullqry;

}
```

You never make it because you are testing for an unobtainable value.
Alter your if statement because the value will always be 8 at that point. Testing for the array length is meaningless there because it will always be the same value there unless you have a loop beforehand that could cause a altering length.

But in this setup it will always be 8.

On a sidenode, you might be better off using $("#selector").text() over .html(). That way you won't have rogue inserted tags by scripts in your way.